# Can I use Unit Testing tools for Integration Testing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I'm preparing to create my first Unit Test, or at least that's how I was thinking of it.  After reading up on unit testing this weekend I suspect I'm actually wanting to do Integration Testing.  I have a black box component from a 3rd party vendor (e.g. a digital scale API) and I want to create tests to test it's usage in my application.  My goal is to determine if a newly released version of said component is working correctly when integrated into my application.

The use of this component is buried deep in my application's code and the methods that utilize it would be very difficult to unit test without extensive refactoring which I can't do at this time.  I plan to, eventually.
Considering this fact I was planning to write custom Unit Tests (i.e. no derived from one of my classes methods or properties) to put this 3rd party component through the same operations that my application will require from it.  I do suspect that I'm circumventing a significant benefit of Unit Testing by doing it this way, but as I said earlier I can't stop and refactor this particular part of my application at this time.

I'm left wondering if I can still write Unit Tests (using Visual Studio) to test this component or is that going against best practices?  From my reading it seems that the Unit Testing tools in Visual Studio are very much designed to do just that - unit test methods and properties of a component.

I'm going in circles in my head, I can't determine if what I want is a Unit Test (of the 3rd party component) or an Integration Test?  I'm drawn to Unit Tests because it's a managed system to execute tests, but I don't know if they are appropriate for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You should watch Colin Bowern's talk on [Building Better Integration Tests](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NewZealand/TechEd-New-Zealand-2012/DEV303) on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Your plan of putting tests around the 3rd party component, to prove that it does what you think it does (what the rest of your system needs it to do) is a good idea. This way when you upgrade the component you can tell quickly if it has changed in ways that mean your system will need to change. This would be an [Integration Contract Test](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationContractTest.html) between that component and the rest of your system.
2. Going forward it would behoove you to put that 3rd party component behind an interface upon which the other components of your system depend. Then those other parts can be tested in isolation from the 3rd party component.

I'd refer to Micheal Feathers' [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) for information on ways to go about adding unit tests to code which is not factored well for unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the 3rd party component the way you are doing it is certainly not against best practices.

Such a test would, however, be classified as a (sub-)system test, since a) the 3rd party component is tested as an isolated (sub-)system, and, b) your testing goal is to validate the behaviour on API level rather than on testing the lower level implementation aspects.

The test would definitely not be classified as an integration test, because you are simply not testing the component together with your code.  That is, you will for example not find out if your component uses the 3rd party component in a way that violates the expectations of the 3rd party component.

That said, I would like to make two points:

- The fact that a test is not a unit-test does not make it less valuable.  I have encountered situations where I told people that their tests were not unit-tests, and they got angry at me because they thought I wanted to tell them that their tests did not make sense - an unfortunate misunderstanding.
- To what category a test belongs is not defined by technicalities like which testing framework you are using.  It is rather defined by the goals you want to achieve with the test, for example, which types of errors you want to find.